# Remove dash from blog title wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi this is my first time using wordpress and php, I created a static page for my front page of the site, and got my news on a separate section, I'm just wondering how do i remove the the dash from the wordpress title in the blog. I understand that its trying pull through the page number, but now that's not required I just need to remove the dash from`wp_title`. Sorry if this post is a duplicate, as I couldn't find any information regarding this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a plugin called [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), you can change the title to whatever you want for any of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Yoast SEO plugin. It looks like my WordPress website was badly configured.

On "Settings - Reading", I was using "Your homepage displays" with "a static page" where I did not select any static page but only a post page with the path `/blog/`.

Instead I had to select "Your latest posts" and then I was able to remove the dash in "Yoast SEO -> Search Appearance -> General (tab)" like mentioned here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-customize-homepage-title-tag/#post-10355658

With this solution I was able to keep blog posts with the "Custom Structure" `/blog/%postname%/` in "Settings - Permalinks". I also added a redirect in my Apache configuration to prevent 404 errors for people using the previous path `/blog` or `/blog/` to get the list of blog posts instead of `/`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/?$ /
```